# Can I make an HTML snippet responsive?

Tags: html, wordpress, responsive, code-snippets, klipfolio

I'm embedding an HTML snippet from [Klipfolio](https://www.klipfolio.com/) to a responsive Wordpress site. The pixel width is static, and I can't figure out how to make it so that the snippet adjusts to screen size per device. Below is the code

```html
<div style="display:inline-block" id="kf-embed-container-f7507c53e69bc38488531eaa17195424"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://embed.klipfolio.com/a/js/embed.api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
KF.embed.embedKlip({
   profile : "f7507c53e69bc38488531eaa17195424",
   settings : {"width":351,"theme":"light","borderStyle":"round","borderColor":"#CCCCCC"},
   title : "Facebook Page Visits (90 Days)",
   actionText : "Need a custom view",
   actionLink : "https://biz.azokaa.com/contact/"
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you using this snippet in an email or landing page?

You must have a specific ID for your snippet. Add the required CSS in your template to make the snippet responsive using that ID.

and use media query like for require screen size

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
#MySnippetID {
 ...CSS here to style... }
}
```